# Access values in array and display on combobox

Tags: vb.net, excel

This is far beyond my skill set, frankly, I have never done anything like this and don't know if it is possible. The procedure below builds an array based on the values of column B6.

```
    Private Sub dsbPositionBoard_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    'This event runs when the dsbPositionBoard starts. The procedure
    'checks for the values in column A of the allPositionsAnualized sheet
    'and populates the combobox with those values. If there are no values the box
    'is disabled.


    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim strRngArr As String
    Dim strChkRange As String

    Try

        xlWB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
        xlWS = DirectCast(xlWB.Sheets("allPositionsAnnualized"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlRng = DirectCast(xlWS.Range("B6", xlWS.Range("B6").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)), Excel.Range)
        strRngArr = String.Empty
        strChkRange = CStr(xlWS.Range("B6").Value)

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strChkRange)) Then

            cmbSelectPosition.Enabled = False

        Else


            'Build a string array delimited by commas
            For i As Integer = 1 To xlRng.Rows.Count
                Dim xlRngCell As Excel.Range = DirectCast(xlRng.Rows(i), Excel.Range)
                strRngArr &= DirectCast(xlRngCell.Value.ToString, String) & ","

            Next

            strRngArr = strRngArr.Remove(strRngArr.Length - 1, 1)
            cmbSelectPosition.Items.AddRange(strRngArr.Split(","c))
            xlRng = Nothing
            xlWS = Nothing

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("There no positions available to select", CType(vbOKOnly, MsgBoxStyle), "Empty Selection")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Now, the function below is used to select the value of cell range, pass it to a helper cell (B37) and then select the corresponding sheet.  The value that this function passes to the helper cell has an equal value in the array above.

```
    Private Function MoveBtwSheets(range As String) As String

    'This function is used to toggle between the position board
    'and the employee board. The function is utilized to select
    'the employees listed in the position board, click on the radio button
    ' and open that employees information in the employee board

    '@parameter range: Selects the cell with the employee name

    Dim xlCalc As Excel.Worksheet


    strMessage = "This employee does not exist. Please verify the employee name"
    strCaption = "Selection Error"
    msgBoxType = MessageBoxIcon.Error
    msgBoxBtns = MessageBoxButtons.OK

    xlWB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)

    xlCalc = CType(xlWB.Worksheets("calculationSheets"), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlWSEE = CType(xlWB.Worksheets("employeeBoard"), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlWSPOS = CType(xlWB.Worksheets("positionBoard"), Excel.Worksheet)


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Try

        xlCalc.Range("B36").Value = xlWSPOS.Range(range).Value

        With xlWSEE

            .Select()
            .Range("E37").Select()


        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(strMessage, strCaption, msgBoxBtns, msgBoxType)

    End Try


    Return ""


End Function
```

So what I wanted to do add to my function is a way to search my array for the value on B37 and then display that value in the combobox in the first procedure. Basically, instead of me dropping down and selecting the item from the array, function would search the array for me and select that item.

If I am not very clear, I can clarify or post screen shots.

Comment: I recommend you to post screenshoots and a simple example as in your other question. As you can see there, once the ideas are clearly transmitted, the help comes quickly.

Comment: @varocarbas, I will get some screenshots ready and post them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a great time to use LINQ. In your initial method (`dsbPositionBoard_Startup()`), you can add each string in Column A into a `List(Of String)`. Then you can query the list using the value of B37 as your search parameter.

Declare the list at the top of your class (outside of any methods)

```
Private _myList As New List(Of String)
```

Add this code to your first method

```
strRngArr = strRngArr.Remove(strRngArr.Length - 1, 1)
cmbSelectPosition.Items.AddRange(strRngArr.Split(","c))

_myList.Add(strRngArr.Split(","c))

xlRng = Nothing
xlWS = Nothing
```

Now add a function along the following lines:

```
Private Function QueryValues(ByVal myParameter as String) As String
     Dim results = From result In _myList Where result = myParameter Select result Distinct
     Return results(0)
End Function
```

Call that function (add some error handling/null reference checks though) with your parameter being the value of cell B37 (or any cell value as string).

Comment: With some minor tweaking I was able to get it to work. Thanks